# How to use RESTful Geoserver?

Tags: rest, geoserver

I'd like to use REST protocol with Geoserver running on a web, but when I enter username and password used to log into web interface, I get `HTTP ERROR: 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource`. Do I need to create separate user with some privileges? May it be webhosting related issue?

Update: I'm able to access existing workspace with web browser, but using QGIS to create new workspace I end up with error mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: I have exact same problem here did you find anything usefull?

Comment: No, I gave it up, but I think it might be qgis-master related problem. Will see what v2.0 is going to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Well I know this is a little late but I will answer it so that hopefully other people with this issue may find it helpful.

The REST process has its own security configuration that needs to be setup in addition to the web interface user. These are different configurations and are setup in different spots. The REST configuration does use that same users you have configured in the web interface it just doesn't use the access rules that you would have set up.

To setup the permissions you need to edit a file in the directory [Geoserver_data}/security called rest.properties.

Please see [here](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/rest_security.html) and [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/rest.html) on what entires to add and edit in this file to provide access to the rest services.